# NetBeans doesn't accept import java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, netbeans, import

In NetBeans the line

> import java.util.Scanner;

isn't accepted. The IDE shows a *cannot find symbol*-Comment. When running, it throws a *cannot find symbol error*.
When I build and run the same without NetBeans by command lines, it is accepted and does, what it ought to do.

Comment: Restarting NetBeans often helps. It's just a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Later, I've created a source package java.util.scanner by my own, and deleted it right away with refactoring the whole project. Then, suddenly, NetBeans accepted the import-command.
I'm glad, that I could fix this problem, but I try to understand, why it has been doing such weird things.